# How do I tie a selected item in a list box to a query (MS Access)?

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I have a couple of list boxes on a form that I've created. One of the listboxes has a bunch of supplier names (lst_SupplierName). Upon selecting a supplier name it then auto-populates all Part Numbers under that supplier in another list box (lst_PartNumber).

I would like to take it a step further. So The Part Number listbox is now populating I would like to select a part number and based on that part number be able to create a query that lists all required attributes associated with that part number from the table it's contained in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 lists, first one that queries supplier table, second one that queries part table that will use value of first list to query parts only for that supplier. Here is sample tables I created:

[image]
[image]

And form:

[image]

The first list row source is:

```
SELECT [tblSuplier].[SupID], [tblSuplier].[SupName] FROM tblSuplier ORDER BY [SupName];
```

Second list row source is:

```
SELECT tblPart.PartID, tblPart.SupID, tblPart.PartName, tblPart.PartDescr FROM tblPart WHERE (((tblPart.SupID)=[Forms]![frmMain]![lstSup]));
```

To make second list update, when you select something in first list, you need to add 'after update' event on first list:

```
Private Sub lstSup_AfterUpdate()

    lstPart.Requery

End Sub
```

Now, you can use after update event to populate different fields on form from parts list the same way - by simply placing value into fields, like txtDescription = lstPart.column(2=3) .

If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response. Is there a way to add multiple statements to the Row Source? I already have the Row Source being used in both lists so when I select the Supplier Name from the first list it then populates the Part Number

Comment: Supplier Name: SELECT dbo_tblOwners.OwnersID, dbo_tblOwners.SupplierName FROM dbo_tblOwners;                                                   Part Number: SELECT dbo_tblBufferPWBoeing.BufferID, dbo_tblBufferPWBoeing.PartNumber FROM dbo_tblBufferPWBoeing;

Comment: You can replace row source on fly, followed by list requery in order to show changes. You can use union query to get data from 2 or more different tables/queries.